# Using sprintf in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, printf

This is similar to a question I asked previously about opening a pdf in Matlab.

```
file = 'sl3_knt_1_2.pdf'
location = 'C:\Program Files\Tracker Software\PDF Viewer\PDFXCview.exe %s'
str = sprintf(location,file);
system(str)
```

This returns the warning:

```
Warning: Invalid escape sequence appears in format string. See help sprintf for valid escape sequences.
```

I think it has something to the location variable getting read as an escape sequence since it uses \ but I am not sure. I cant seem to get this to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
file = 'sl3_knt_1_2.pdf'
location = 'C:\Program Files\Tracker Software\PDF Viewer\PDFXCview.exe'

str = sprintf('%s %s',location, file)

system(str)
```

Answer (score 3):

The easy solution is to use '/' instead of '\', which works on all platforms, including Windows. '\' is problematic being a special character.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can change your location string like that:

```
location = 'C:\\Program Files\\Tracker Software\\PDF Viewer\\PDFXCview.exe %s'
```

Usually `\` is used for special characters. For instance `\n` is an end of line. So when you really want to write `\`, you need to escape it by using `\`. So, you need to write `\\` in this case